# Too many labels when using datetime format on x-axis

Tags: java, android, teechart

When adding `DateTime` values to an `Area` series, the labels are repeated as shown below. How do you avoid this weirdness?

[image: 3 values, 6 labels]

Should be "31/12/2012" and "01/01/2013".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set a DateTime increment for the bottom axis as explained in tutorial 4:

```
tChart1.getAxes().getBottom().setIncrement(Utils.getDateTimeStep(DateTimeStep.ONEDAY));
```

Tutorials can be found in the so called folder included with TeeChart files.

Comment: Thanks. I did try `DateTimeStep.ONEDAY` (note your trailing 's' typo) without calling `getDateTimeStep()`. That function did the trick!

Comment: @l33t you're welcome. Thanks for the feedback also. I have made the correction in my reply and we will try to update it in the tutorials.